# MVC partial view updated but not showing in main view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, view

i am trying to get my partial view updated in my main view after ajax button click. I step through the partial view and the model has the correct values. I store the values in html in order for them to be displayed in the main view however. The new values are not displayed. I was wondering if someone could help me.

View Model:

```
namespace myApp.ViewModels
{
    public class mrfResult
    {
        public string mrf { get; set; }
        public string round { get; set; }
        public string route { get; set; }
        public string supplier { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string deadline { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RFInfo(RfInfo pRfInfo)
{
  List<mrfResult> newResult = new List<mrfResult>();
.....
mrfResult nRow = new mrfResult();
nRow.mrf = pRfRow; nRow.round = pRfInfo.round; nRow.route = routeRow.ServiceId.ToString();nRow.supplier = supRow.name; nRow.status = statName; nRow.deadline = supRow.deadline.ToString();
newResult.Add(nRow);
.....
return PartialView("~/Views/RFMaster/_Partials/_GetRFDetails.cshtml", newResult);
}
```

Partial View:

```
@model List<myApp.ViewModels.mrfResult>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

    @section scripts {
        <script src="~/Javascript/RFInfo.js"></script>
    }
    <div>
        @{            
            string routeName = "(a - b)";
            string servId = "";

            if (Model != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {
                    servId = Model[i].supplier;
                    break;
                }                
            }
        }
        <span>@routeName</span><br />
        <span>@servId</span><br />
        <span>@routeName</span><br />
    </div>
```

Main View:

```
@model List<myApp.ViewModels.mrfResult>
    @{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        }

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/multi-select/multiple-select.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/multi-select/multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/CSS/css_RFInfo.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Javascript/RFInfo.js"></script>
}
@{
    int cnt = 0;
}
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>RF Information</h1>

        ............

        <div class="contRfDetails">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/RFMaster/_Partials/_GetRFDetails.cshtml")
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#btnFind").click(function () {
        var getRf = $("#ddlRf").val();       
        var getRound = $("#ddlRnd").val();
        var getRoute = $("#ddlRte").multipleSelect('getSelects').toString();
        var getSupp = $("#ddlSup").multipleSelect('getSelects').toString();
        var getStat = $("#ddlStat").multipleSelect('getSelects').toString();

        var params = {
            'rf': getRf, 'route': getRoute, 'round': getRound, 'supp': getSupp, 'stat': getStat
        };
        var json = JSON.stringify(params);
        $.ajax({
            url: "../RFMaster/RFInfo",
            type: "POST",
            data: json,
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Process Successful');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error")   
            }
        });
    });
});
```

in the main view when first loaded the div that has the partial view displays:

(a - b)

(a - b)

which is correct.

after pressing the 'btnFind' button the controller httppost action result function is fired. The model is populated against the jquery parameters. The model is then sent to the partial view. A loop is performed on the model in the partial view. One of the values is retrieved (sup1) and stored in a variable 'servId'. That variable is then assigned within a span '@servId
.

The div in the main view should now look like this:

(a - b)

sup1

(a - b)

but all i'm getting back is the original data from the view.

(a - b)

(a - b)

Comment: I don't see anywhere the code that append the result of the ajax call to the `<div class="contRfDetails"></div>`.  In the success section of the ajax call, what happen if you put `$('.contRfDetails').append(data);`

Answer (score 0):

The js should update a html element with the data from the controller. 
Update the lines of the script from :

```
*success: function (data) {
            alert('Process Successful');
        },*
```

to

```
success: function (data) {
           $('.contRfDetails').html(data);
        },
```